# How to query all items in an array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

if I have an array with multiple strings like `lineItems.0.domain`, `lineItems.1.domain` etc. is there an easier way to know if any of those `domains` contains some `searchText`?

Not sure how to do it all in one, so just using a lot of $or statements

`{ "lineItems.0.domain": /.*mercari.*/i, $or: [ { "lineItems.1.domain": "item.mercari.com" }, { $or: [ { "lineItems.2.domain": "item.mercari.com" }, { $or: [ { "lineItems.3.domain": "item.mercari.com" }, { $or: [ { "lineItems.4.domain": "item.mercari.com" }, { $or: [ { "lineItems.5.domain": "item.mercari.com" }, { $or: [ { "lineItems.6.domain": "item.mercari.com" } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] }`

Comment: `"lineitems.domain": /.*mercari.*/i`. How did you get to thinking you needed every index?

Comment: cool! thanks! "How did you get..." because that's what I get `lineItem.0.domain` when I drag domain into the query builder in Studio 3t. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Not exactly a new question, but for the life of me I cannot seem to find anything that does not mention `$elemMatch` even though you don't need that for a "single" condition on the array elements. Bit surprised the 3T GUI is doing that. You should make a complaint, because that's just plain misleading.